# What the best approach when allocating a set of people randomly in different days?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

So, I have an insteresting problem. But not sure if here is the place I must post it.

**THE CONTEXT**

Basically I want to make diferent study groups that

- Have a number of students
- Have a number of tutors

But, each person has a set of available days of the week to participate of one study session.
And each person can be part of only one study group

Example of availability

```
StudentA = [Tuesday, Wednesday]
StudentB = [Wednesday, Saturday]
StudentC = [Saturday]

TutorA= [Tuesday, Friday]
TutorB = [Tuesday]
```

I must make study group that

- have between 2 and 4 Students
- have between 2 and 3 Tutors

---

**MY APPROACH**

I'm using python 3
I'm trying to generate all the possible combinations and filter the actually possible cases with a list of available people:

1. I name each combination of availability of students with a code:

   - [Tuesday] => "p1"
   - [Wednesday] => "p2"
   - ...
   - [Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday] => "p7"
2. Same thing with the tutors

   - [Tuesday] => "c1"
   - [Wednesday] => "c2"
   - ...
   - [Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday] => "c7"
3. I use itertools.combinations_with_replacement to make all the

- combinations of students
- combinations of tutors

4. I combinate both previous combinations into the possible study groups
5. I combinate all the teams to generate scenarios
6. I filter using the restriction

   - Each person is allocated in one study group
   - Each person is participating only once
   - There is more students than tutors

---

**THE PROBLEM**

As one can expect, the combinations and permutations are generating a very large number of possibilites.

I can accept to constrain the number of days to three.

But still I'm not being able to have a acceptable performance for my regular computer

Is ther any better approach I'm not seeing? I was imagining if some algebra linear could transform this problem in a set of equations, but not sure

Obs: The number of students and tutors are much larger (between 20 and 50 each)

Comment: Did you actually mean **I must make teams that ....have between 2 and 3 Coachs**?  Do you really mean there are 2 or 3 coaches per team?

Comment: Yes. I'm actually not making teams, but I tried to adapt the example. I will update with another anology

Comment: With the minimum amount of Students and Tutors (2), what happens with the people that are left over? In the Example you supplied, you would never find any group with atleast 2 Students and 2 Tutors.

Comment: @miwin, i've added an observation to answer you!

Comment: Does the solution have to be without importing libraries or can you use a tool like [Google ortools](https://developers.google.com/optimization)?  In particular, the Contraint Program Solver i.e. [CP-SAT Solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver) was designed for problems like this.  I can show an answer using this tool is that's of intrest.

Comment: @DarryIG, yes I can use imported libraries or external tools

Comment: @MatheusSantosOliveira--I posted a solution based upon ortools. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @MatheusSantosOliveira--was the solution I posed of any help?

Answer (score 0):

**The Context**

Specify students by availability in a 7 day week

Example:

```
 [
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
  ]
```

Each row is for a student (i.e. 4 students in this case)
Each column is for a day of the week (i.e. 7), with 1 or 0 for available or unavailable, respectively.

So `[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` means student 0 is available on the first two days of the week i.e. Monday and Tuesday.

TA availability specified similarly

Example:

```
[
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
]
```

Shows there are three TAs, with the first TA available every day.

Sessions are organized as:

```
               7 Days with N sessions per day numbered 0 to N-1

Session    Monday   Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday   Saturday   Sunday
0          session  session  session   session   session   session    session
1          session  session  session   session   session   session    session
2          session  session  session   session   session   session    session
3          session  session  session   session   session   session    session
            ...
N-1        session  session  session   session   session   session    session
```

N is unknown, but we can choose a suitably large value (i.e. if N get just leads to more sessions not assigned to students or TAs).

Constraints are:

- 2 to 4 students per session
- students are in only one session per week
- students are only assigned a session on their available days
- 2 to 3 TAs per session
- TAs are only assigned sessions on their availablel days

The **goal** is to find an assignment of students and TAs that satisfy the constraints.

**Approach**

Use Google [ortools Contstraint Solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver)

ortools allows this combinatorial problem to be described as a search problem

Reference: [ortools youtube Tutorail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hod0L0zfnZs&t=2461s)

**Code**

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model    # Google Constraint Modeling Tool (https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver)
from tabulate import tabulate              # For displaying results in table form (https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

week_days = ("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday")
                                      
def main(student_availability, ta_availability):
    ########################################################
    # Information Setup
    ########################################################
    num_days = len(week_days)     # days in a week we are using
                                    
    num_students = len(student_availability)
    num_days = len(student_availability[0])
    all_students = range(num_students)
    all_days = range(num_days)
    
    # Show student availability
    special = u'\u2713'
    tmp_table = [[special if c else 'x' for c in row] for row in student_availability]
    display_table(tmp_table, "Students", "Students Availability")
 
 
    num_tas = len(ta_availability)
    all_tas = range(num_tas)
    
    # Show TA availability
    tmp_table = [[special if c else 'x' for c in row] for row in ta_availability]
    display_table(tmp_table, "     TAs", "\nTA Availability")
    
    # Learning sessions 
    #  Model as max sessions per day, 7 days a weeks
    #  The solver will decide which sessions are assigned students and TAs
    max_sessions_per_day = num_students       # Would actually use a lot fewer sessions per day
    all_sessions = range(max_sessions_per_day)
 
    ########################################################
    # Creates the model
    ########################################################
    model = cp_model.CpModel()
    
    ########################################################
    # Specify Constraints
    ########################################################
    
    session_zero = {}             # sessions with zero students and TAs (i.e. unused)
    session_bound = {}            # sessions which satisfy the student and TA occupancy bounds
    for d in all_days:
        for session in all_sessions:
            session_zero[(d, session)] = model.NewBoolVar('zero%id%ig' % (d, session))
            session_bound[(d, session)] = model.NewBoolVar('bound%id%ig' % (d, session))
            model.Add(session_zero[(d, session)] + session_bound[(d, session)]==1)  # Sessions are used or unused

    # Student Constraints
    student_group = {}
    for s in all_students:
        for d in all_days:
            for session in all_sessions:
                student_group[(s, d, session)] = model.NewBoolVar('student_assigned%is%id%ig' % (s, d, session))
                
    # Each used session has between 2 & 4 students
    for d in all_days:
        for session in all_sessions:
            # Meeting define by (d, session)
            students_assigned = sum(student_group[(s, d, session)] for s in all_students)
            model.Add(students_assigned==0).OnlyEnforceIf(session_zero[(d, session)])
            model.Add(students_assigned >= 2).OnlyEnforceIf(session_bound[(d, session)])
            model.Add(students_assigned <= 4).OnlyEnforceIf(session_bound[(d, session)])
                
    # Every student is assigned one session in the week on their available days
    for s, row in enumerate(student_availability):
        available_days = [d for d, v in enumerate(row) if v > 0]
        model.Add(sum(student_group[(s, d, session)] for d in available_days for session in all_sessions) == 1)
        
    # No Studentss are assigned sessions on their unavailable days
    for t, row in enumerate(student_availability):
        unavailable_days = [d for d, v in enumerate(row) if v == 0]
        model.Add(sum(student_group[(t, d, session)] for d in unavailable_days for session in all_sessions) == 0)
                
        
    # TA Constraint
    ta_group = {}
    for t in all_tas:
        for d in all_days:
            for session in all_sessions:
                ta_group[(t, d, session)] = model.NewBoolVar('ta_assigned%is%id%ig' % (t, d, session))

            
    # Each session has between 2 & 3 TAs
    for d in all_days:
        for session in all_sessions:
            ta_assigned = sum(ta_group[(t, d, session)] for t in all_tas)
            model.Add(ta_assigned==0).OnlyEnforceIf(session_zero[(d, session)])
            model.Add(ta_assigned >= 2).OnlyEnforceIf(session_bound[(d, session)])
            model.Add(ta_assigned <= 3).OnlyEnforceIf(session_bound[(d, session)])

    # TAs are assigned on available days
    for t, row in enumerate(ta_availability):
        available_days = [d for d, v in enumerate(row) if v > 0]
        model.Add(sum(ta_group[(t, d, session)] for d in available_days for session in all_sessions) >= 0)
        
    # No TAs are assigned on their unavailable days
    for t, row in enumerate(ta_availability):
        unavailable_days = [d for d, v in enumerate(row) if v == 0]
        model.Add(sum(ta_group[(t, d, session)] for d in unavailable_days for session in all_sessions) == 0)
                
    # Creates the solver and solve.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    
    # Sets a time limit of 10 seconds.
    solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 10.0
 
    # Display the first five solutions.
    a_few_solutions = range(2)
    solution_printer = StudentsPartialSolutionPrinter(student_group,
                                                      num_students, 
                                                      ta_group, 
                                                      num_tas,
                                                      num_days, 
                                                      max_sessions_per_day,
                                                      student_availability,
                                                      ta_availability,
                                                      a_few_solutions)
    
    status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)
    print()
    print('Status = %s' % solver.StatusName(status))
    print('Number of solutions found: %i' % solution_printer.solution_count())


    # Statistics.
    print()
    print('Statistics')
    print('  - conflicts       : %i' % solver.NumConflicts())
    print('  - branches        : %i' % solver.NumBranches())
    print('  - wall time       : %f s' % solver.WallTime())
    print('  - solutions found : %i' % solution_printer.solution_count())

class StudentsPartialSolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    def __init__(self, 
                 student_group,
                 num_students, 
                 ta_group, 
                 num_tas,
                 num_days, 
                 max_sessions_per_day, 
                 student_availability,
                 ta_availability,
                 sols):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self._student_group = student_group
        self._num_students = num_students
        self._ta_group = ta_group
        self._num_tas = num_tas
        self._num_days = num_days
        self._max_sessions_per_day = max_sessions_per_day
        self._student_availability = student_availability
        self._ta_availability = ta_availability
        self._solutions = set(sols)
        self._solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        if self._solution_count in self._solutions:
            print('\nSolution %i' % self._solution_count)
            # Student Scheduling
            table = [[u'\u2713' if col else 'x' for col in row] for row in self._student_availability]
            
            for session in range(self._max_sessions_per_day):
                    for d in range(self._num_days):
                        for s in range(self._num_students):
                            if self.Value(self._student_group[(s, d, session)]):
                                table[s][d] = table[s][d] + f" {week_days[d][:3]}-{session}"
            print()    
            display_table(table, "Students", "Students Scheduling")
                      
   
            # TA scheduling
            table = [[u'\u2713' if col else 'x' for col in row] for row in self._ta_availability]
            for session in range(self._max_sessions_per_day):
                    for d in range(self._num_days):
                        for s in range(self._num_tas):
                            if self.Value(self._ta_group[(s, d, session)]):
                                table[s][d] = table[s][d] + f" {week_days[d][:3]}-{session}"
                
            
            print()
            display_table(table, "     TAs", "TA Scheduling")

        self._solution_count += 1
 
    def solution_count(self):
        return self._solution_count

def display_table(data, data_category, message):
    ''' Display data in tabular form'''
    table = [[f'{idx:>8}'] + row for idx, row in enumerate(data)]
    print(message)
    print(tabulate(table, headers=(data_category,) + week_days, tablefmt="rst"))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Student Information
    student_availability = [
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
    ]
    
    # TA Information
    ta_availability = [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    ]
    
    # Find solutions
    main(student_availability, ta_availability)
```

**Output**

The specified problem required three sessions
--Monday (Mon-3) and Thursday (Thu-0).

```
Students Availability
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========
  Students  Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday    Thursday    Friday    Saturday    Sunday
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========
         0  ✓         ✓          x            x           x         x           x
         1  ✓         x          ✓            x           x         x           ✓
         2  ✓         ✓          x            ✓           x         ✓           ✓
         3  x         ✓          x            ✓           x         ✓           x
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========

TA Availability
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========
       TAs  Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday    Thursday    Friday    Saturday    Sunday
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========
         0  ✓         ✓          ✓            ✓           ✓         ✓           ✓
         1  ✓         x          x            x           x         x           x
         2  ✓         x          x            ✓           x         x           ✓
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========

Solution 0

Students Scheduling
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========
  Students  Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday    Thursday    Friday    Saturday    Sunday
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========
         0  ✓ Mon-3   ✓          x            x           x         x           x
         1  ✓ Mon-3   x          ✓            x           x         x           ✓
         2  ✓         ✓          x            ✓ Thu-0     x         ✓           ✓
         3  x         ✓          x            ✓ Thu-0     x         ✓           x
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========

TA Scheduling
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========
       TAs  Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday    Thursday    Friday    Saturday    Sunday
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========
         0  ✓ Mon-3   ✓          ✓            ✓ Thu-0     ✓         ✓           ✓
         1  ✓ Mon-3   x          x            x           x         x           x
         2  ✓         x          x            ✓ Thu-0     x         x           ✓
==========  ========  =========  ===========  ==========  ========  ==========  ========

Status = OPTIMAL
Number of solutions found: 1

Statistics
  - conflicts       : 0
  - branches        : 0
  - wall time       : 0.014649 s
  - solutions found : 1
```